# Using generics to return more than one type

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist, return-type

I am currently trying to refactor some of my code and have stumbled into a feature I haven't used before in Java related to Generics.

I am attempting to return an `ArrayList<?>` of a specific type based on the parameter passed into the method. The Parameter accepts an Enumeration that specifies the desired type of `ArrayList<T>` To return, something like this, however I am getting errors from the method prototype:

```
// Retrieves an ArrayList of questions available for a particular QuestionType
    public <T extends Question> ArrayList<T extends Question> getQuestions(QuestionType type) {
        switch (type) {
        case BASE_QUESTION:
            return mQuestions; // ArrayList<Question>

        case MULTIPLE_ANSWER_QUESTION:
        case MULTIPLE_CHOICE_QUESTION:
        case TRUE_FALSE_QUESTION:
            return mMultipleAnswerQuestions; // ArrayList<MultipleAnswerQuestion>

        case MATCHING_QUESTION:
            return mMatchingQuestions; // ArrayList<MatchingQuestion>

        case BLANK_QUESTION:
            return mBlankQuestions; // ArrayList<BlankQuestion>

        default:
            // TODO Perfect place to throw an exception
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: Provided a non-existant QuestionType");
        }
    }
```

Additional Information:
This method exists within a custom object that contains multiple ArrayList of Questions organised by their type. This method does not Exist within the SuperClass of the Question type.

```
// CLASS HIERARCHY
// SuperClass
Question

// SubClasses of Question
MultipleAnswerQuestion
MultipleChoiceQuestion
TrueFalseQuestion
MatchingQuestion
BlankQuestion
```

Can some explain to me how to prototype a method that achieves this task?

Thanks for your understanding and help.

Comment: You don't need to specify `extends Question` again in the return type. You already specified that. Also, in this case, it seems a wildcard might be better because you don't use `T`

Comment: Could you provide an Answer demonstrating this approach?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Eclipse: "Return Type Missing" and "Syntax error on 'extends' token"

Comment: Thank you everyone, All three answers specifying the use of bounded wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those particular compilation errors you got were probably because the syntax error of declaring the bounds on `T` a second time prevented the compiler from recognizing `ArrayList<T extends Question>` as your return type. So if you either remove `extends Question` or change your return type to a bounded wildcard the compilation errors *should* go away.

In generic methods, you only specify bounds on the type parameter *once* -- when declaring them at the beginning of the method signature. In other words, just use `ArrayList<T>` as the return type instead of `ArrayList<T extends Question>`, because you already specified what the bounds were on `T` in the generic method.

So you'd end up with something like

```
public <T extends Question> ArrayList<T> getQuestions(QuestionType type) {
    ...
}
```

In addition, because you don't appear to actually *use* `T` in your method, it's probably a better idea to skip the generic method altogether and just use a bounded wildcard in your return value, like this:

```
public ArrayList<? extends Question> getQuestions(QuestionType type) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your method signature to:

```
public ArrayList<? extends Question> getQuestions(QuestionType type)
```

On a side note, you might want to just create an [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) to map your lists instead of doing a `switch` every time.

Answer (score 1):

The correct prototype is `public <T extends Question> ArrayList<T> getQuestions(QuestionType type)` or `public ArrayList<? extends Question> getQuestions(QuestionType type)`